# BigQuery timestamp partitioned table issue

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm having a issue while creating a table in Google BigQuery partitioned by day using a timestamp column.
The problem arise when I'm trying to insert a record with a timestamp in the range between "1960-01-01" and "2023-03-05", the inserted data are not present in any partition, neither in the `__NULL__` partition nor in the `__UNPARTITIONED__` partition.

I tried to insert any date format, timestamp, but I got the same problem, and I'm expecting to insert the rows correctly.

Comment: Did you query your table to look at this element?

Comment: Yes but these elements are not present in the table (elements outside this range are inserted correctly in the table)